# Is there a way i can add html code in .map function in react?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to react and using .map() to list some items with a 
 tag appended to it. The issue that I am facing is when i append a 
 tag it doesn't do a line break. It just shows 
 next to every store. Below is my code i am using. Any help would be really appreicated.

```
   return <div> {stores.map((store) => store + "<br>")} </div>
```

Comment: Because it's just a string, not an element. Try e.g. `<>{store}<br/></>`, otherwise you have to "dangerously set inner HTML".

Comment: No, you can't (shouldn't) add html. However, you can return jsx elements from the `map` callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. But you should wrap them inside one tag e.g. `<div>` or `<>`.

```
return (<div>
         {stores.map((store) => (
             <>{store}<br></> // You can also use `<div>{store}</div>` since `div` is achieving the br effect.
         ))}
       </div>)
```

Comment: Wrapping them in `<div>`s will not achieve the effect that `<br>` is supposed to achieve. Also I guess in JSX you'll have to write `<br />`?